# Why not always use enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Tags: html, forms, enctype

When building HTML forms why do we not always use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`multipart/form-data` is a lot bulkier than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`; the latter is just a bunch of keys and values (and can be parsed the same way whether for `GET` or `POST`), whereas the former requires full MIME support, and is thus more useful when you have data that can't simply be represented as key/value pairs.

Comment: We use enctype=“multipart/form-data” always since some months (even for forms without file uploads). It works nice. This makes our templates easier. One small step into the direction "conditionless". I did not do any byte counting since it does not matter in my context.

Answer (score 7):

Because it's a pain to handle, both on the server and in custom clients. Simple is better than complicated, unless simple just doesn't work.

Comment: I don't feel pain if the CPU is a little bit busy. Do you think this overhead is measurable?

Answer (score 1):

With PHP it doesn't matter what kind o enctype the form had. You always get key/value pairs.

So if harder coding is the only reason not to and you are using PHP, just use enctype="multipart/form-data".

Is there any other reason?

Comment: That's *just* PHP. There are more web programming languages in world than only PHP.

Comment: @BalusC: He said "and you are using PHP". Bruno wasn't talking about other web programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Mulipart implicits that we are going to use different mime-types. For example, sending a binary file, you will have one part with the x-www-form-urlencoded part and the other with the octet-stream. Most of the times what you send is from the same mime type.