# How can i upload both $_POST and $_FILES at the same time? PHP

Tags: php, forms, file, post, submit

I am a student trying to figure out, how i can simultaneously upload an files (jpg, jpeg, png) along with sending an message through PHP?

Currently i have tried two things.

1. Making a single form in html, and trying to submit to the same .php file. While following two separate tutorials, combining them. (See picture)
2. Making two different forms, which i want to be submitted from the same html page, with the same ''submit''. Is this possible?

So far i think i figured out that it is not possible to use both $_POST and $_FILES from the same form, is this true?

Any ideas how to fix the original code i already have, and if not, what is the easiest way to do it.

**I am learning, so the easiest way is prefered :)
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIupi.png)
[PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zviyM.png)

Comment: you can of course send both in the same form . just use post and set enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form tag

Comment: `is this true?`...no, not at all. I don't known what examples etc you've been reading. You can do it all from one form. If you're having trouble with that, post a [mre] of the issue and clarify the exact problem.

Comment: `Any ideas how to fix the original code i already have`...not if you don't show it to us!! Please don't post images of code, it's really unhelpful - see [ask]. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: P.s. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11040586/5947043

Comment: Thanks Guys, i figured it out. 

I will also try and follow your comments next time i post a problem here. I was not aware, but i have read How to ask now!