# Why I can't pass this value from a form to a .php file that have to handle it?

Tags: php, forms

I am pretty new in PHP and I have the following problem passing a data from a form to a .php file that have to handle it.

So this is the form into the rendered page:

```
<form method="post" action="common/remove-booking_pc.php" class="ajax-form">
    <input id="id_booking" name="id_booking" value="5" type="hidden">

    <a href="/PandaOk/templates/default/common/remove-booking_pc.php" type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
            Conferma
    </a>
</form>
```

It is what is shown looking into the browser code. As you can see it is passing a single data field, this:

```
<input id="id_booking" name="id_booking" value="5" type="hidden">
```

The passed value is **5**.

So when I submit this form it is rendered by this file **remove-booking_pc.php**:

```
<?php
    $id_booking = $_POST['id_booking'];

    $result_remove_booking = $db->query("UPDATE pm_booking SET status= " . $id_booking);

?>
```

The problem is that the **$id_booking** is **null** and the **$_POST** is an empty array.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I correctly pass this value?

Comment: You are not submitting the form, you would need a submit button.  You are clicking a hyperlink, there is no `<a href="... " type="submit">`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Side note: Your query will update your entire db without a WHERE clause, unless that's what you want.

Comment: In short _You have a long way to go to complete this page_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to use anchor to submit form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983076/is-it-safe-to-use-anchor-to-submit-form)

Answer (score 2):

Your submit is an anchor, not a form submission, so the receiving page will never receive any POST data.

Simply replace your anchor with a `button` [or `input`] of the type `submit` and the form will be submitted as expected.

```
<form method="post" action="common/remove-booking_pc.php" class="ajax-form">
    <input id="id_booking" name="id_booking" value="5" type="hidden">

    <button type="submit" class="fa fa-power-off" value="Submit">Conferma</button>

</form>
```

---

**Other things you should be considering:**

- Your form is vulnerable to Cross Site Request Forgery [[CSRF]](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))
- Your database is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).
- As pointed out by Fred, your SQL (`UPDATE pm_booking SET status=`) currently will update every row in the table, without any qualification. Use [`WHERE`](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/where.php) in your SQL.
- If dealing with file uploads, your HTML form should as best practise have an `enctype` value.

  ```
  <form enctype='multipart/form-data' ... >
  ```

Comment: *"Your HTML form should as best practise have an enctype value. Typically

<form enctype='multipart/form-data' ... >"* - This only applies when dealing with files. Edit: This comment as per http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43767890/2

Comment: @Fred-ii- no worries. Although I'm not sure when there would be reasons *not* to use that enctype?

Comment: If files aren't being handled, why the extra keystrokes? Saving my fingers for playing more notes ♫ on my guitar ;-)

Comment: [I did read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039166/why-not-always-use-enctype-multipart-form-data), but as for keystrokes, I forget some people still type forms out manually, I have auto complete, I write `<form` and the rest is auto-generated `<form action="" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" accept-charset="UTF-8" name="">` (obviously I adjust the action and add a name)

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Button` to submit the form, in this case you are using a `href` hyper link. Example below:

```
<input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: *"OR Make it simple:

<button type="button">Click Me!</button>"* - You should have left it the way it was; without that. Those only work in JS/ajax. Edit: This comment as per original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43767893/1