# Support for <input .. formenctype="multipart/form-data" >

Tags: html, file-upload, browser

I would like to avoid the `formenctype` attribute on the form element. I would like to use the `formenctype` attribute on the **file input** element. This makes my form templates more generic and less complicated.

See related question [Use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` always or never?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060780/use-enctype-multipart-form-data-always-or-never/45148463)

I am unsure which browsers support this attribute.

Which browser which is still supported by the vendor does not support the `formenctype` attribute on the file input element?

Comment: Just for the records. I use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` since several months now. Works perfectly. This means less conditions, less bugs, more fun for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click the link in your question to the related question
2. Click the link in the answer about `formenctype`
3. Scroll down

There is a [browser compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Browser_compatibility) on that page.

In short: The current version of all major browsers supports the feature. You have to go back to IE9 before you lose support.